# How do I check if a tkinter window is minimized?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How do I check if the tkinter window is minimized?
Something like this:

```py
from tkinter import *
def check_if_window_minimized():
    if root.minimized:
        print("True")
    else:
        print("False")
root = Tk()
while True:
    check_if_window_minimized()
root.mainloop()
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Try `root.winfo_ismapped()`.  Also use `.after()` instead of while loop.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
from tkinter import *


root=Tk()

if root.state()=="iconic":
    print("minimized")


root.mainloop()
```

root.state() can show your window status.